# Can I enter Bulgaria (Schengen joiner state) if I have a Schengen ban?

Tags: visas, schengen, romania, removal, bulgaria

I am from Argentina and I would like to know whether I can enter Bulgaria.

I  overstayed in the Schengen area and when I exited Greece, on my way to Turkey, I was told that have a penalty of 1200€ or a 4-year entry ban.

As I understand it, countries like Bulgaria, Romania and Croatia are part of the EU, but are not yet Schengen, correct?

I want to travel this summer in the Balkan Peninsula but I don't know if my ban includes the joiner states.

---

Note: Bulgaria and Romania are currently in the process of joining the Schengen Area.

Note: A visa is generally not required for Argentine nationals visiting Bulgaria.

Comment: Profoundly good question! I have edited it to add some background info and to broaden the scope a bit.

Comment: I was told that have a penalty of 1200€ or a 4-year entry ban. -- did you pay? Do you have a ban? Is there any paperwork showing it?

Comment: I didn't pay, they told me I must pay only if I wanna go in again... I signed some papers but didn't get any with me...

Comment: The thing is I tried to enter again anyway, love is sometimes stupid... They didn't let me in and told me again about my penalization and refuse my entry. This time I got a paper saying the reason why I got rejected is because I've already been 3 months in a 6 months period in member countries of the UE. doesn't say about any penalization.

Comment: I'll be 3 months out when I plan to enter Bulgaria, will they let me in?

Comment: There is a huge difference between being refused entry and being banned. Could you scan and upload the paperwork so that your question, whether you'll be allowed to enter, can be answered?

Comment: Hello! Thanks for the answer. I know is different things, and it looks like I got both :).   The only paper I have if of the refuse, bout the ban and penalization don't have, not even a bad stamp in my passport

Answer (score 4):

Bulgaria has access and full use of the  [Schengen Information System (SIS)](https://www.mvr.bg/en/shengen/sis.htm) that supports external border control and law enforcement cooperation in the Schengen States.

[Bulgaria](http://www.mfa.bg/en/pages/109/index.html), in its efforts toward full Schengen status, is able to access the SIS information from within its border protection and passport and visa control system. While your citizenship doesn't require a visa to enter Bulgaria, your Schengen ban would show up when you present for entry at a border.